# How to sort array of objects according to epoch time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, priority-queue, epoch

I want to arrange the data which I am getting from the API according to the time.
Here is one of the objects inside the array.

```
{
    "orderId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "amount": 10,
    "status": "CREATED",
    "transactionTime": 1651498914,
    "type": "ADD",
    "mode": "UPI",
    "bankAccountId": {
        "bankAccountNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ifsc": "XXXX XXXX XXXX"
    }
}
```

I want to arrange the array in descending order according to the **transactionTime** which is an epoch time.

My initial approach.

```
data.map((item) => item.transactionTime)
   .sort()
   .reverse()
   .map((item) => {
        return data.find((i) => i.transactionTime == item);
})
```

This code is perfectly working but as you can see, it is not a good way to do this.
So I want a more optimized solution. Someone suggested using a priority queue.

Comment: "which is an epoch time." -- isn't every time-and-date system an epoch-relative value?

Comment: `.map( e => Array.find( x => ) )` has **O(n^2)** runtime - don't do that.

Comment: All you need is `const sorted = Array.from( data ).sort( ( x, y ) => x.transactionTime - y.transactionTime );`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can directly subtract the times in the `sort` callback.

```js
data.sort((a, b)=>b.transactionTime - a.transactionTime);
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to such obvious duplicates but flag them as duplicate instead ...